# Gradle crush while building android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to build my project (started with gradle 1.10) using gradle 1.12 (I've just updated to android studio 0.5.8). Here's the message that I receive on a compileDebugJava step:

[image: gradle daemon error]

I ain't that good in gradle, but I can say that I didn't stop or kill that build daemon (I even don't know how to control it). Does anyone know what to do with it?

Here's some snippets from logs and project files:

Gradle console:

```
Executing tasks: [:projectname:compileDebugJava]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
:projectname:preBuild
:projectname:preDebugBuild
:projectname:checkDebugManifest
:projectname:preReleaseBuild
:projectname:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV71910Library UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices4452Library UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:prepareDebugDependencies
:projectname:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:projectname:compileDebugJava
```

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.12-all.zip
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 25
        versionName "1.2.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'GENERATED_FOLDER']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
    }
}

repositories{
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4+'

    //lib: Google JSON mapper
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'

    //lib: Async image loader with cache support
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.1'

    //lib: android annotations
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0.1"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0.1"

    //lib: groundy (Async tasks)
    apt 'com.telly:groundy-compiler:1.5'
    compile 'com.telly:groundy:1.5'
}

//adding annotations preprocessors
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName 'ru.projectname'
    }
}
```

Comment: Try update build tools in sdk manager

Comment: Done. Now I'm using build tools v 19.1, but still nothing.